# How can I access data from two databases, in a single entity, using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, dao

I'm trying to learn how I can access two databases. For this I developed a project using hibernate and created two connection like this.

A connection contains only data of a fictitious student, another contains an identification photo. I imagine a database of files which contains PDFs, images...

The image has a composite primary key as it is divided into rows of bytes.

I can connect individually on each base, but I can not when I try to use them at the same time.

Photo.class

```
@IdClass(PhotoId.class)
public class Photo {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id_arquivo")
   private int idArquivo;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "item", nullable = false)
   private long item;

   @Column(name = "conteudo", nullable = false)
   private byte[] conteudo;

   @Column(name = "size", nullable = false)
   private long size;
...
}

class PhotoId implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private int idArquivo;
   private long item;
...
}
```

Person.class

```
public class Person {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id_pessoa")
   private int idPessoa;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "id_arquivo_foto", referencedColumnName = "id_arquivo")
   private Photo photo;
}
```

This works perfectly when I call in DAO.
I have two "hibernate.cfg" and two hibernate util to connect.

PersonDAO.class

```
public class PersonDAO{
   private static PersonDAO personDAOInstance;

   public static PersonDAO getInstance(){
       if(personDAOInstance == null) {
           personDAOInstance = new PersonDAO();
       }
       return(personDAOInstance);
   }

   public Person getPersonById(int id){
       Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
       Person person = null;

       try {
           Query consulta = session.getNamedQuery("Person.buscarPorId");
           consulta.setInteger("id", id);

           person = (Person) consulta.uniqueResult();
       } catch(RuntimeException ex) {
           throw ex;
       } finally {
           session.close();
       }

       return(person);
   }
}
```

I have another DAO just for the photo, PhotoDAO.class is the same as PersonDAO.class with the necessary mapping changes.
I call the object and it always gives error, but when I comment the photo field in Person.class works, when I call Photo.class it works, but never Person.class with photo.

I call it this way:

```
Person person = personDAO.getPersonById(2);
```

I do not know if I should do

> private List photo

, or it is another problem with the connect mode, since Photo.class is mapped by hibernate_base_arquivos.cfg.xml and Person.class by hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it like this:

```
Before
public class Person {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id_pessoa")
   private int idPessoa;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "id_arquivo_foto", referencedColumnName = "id_arquivo")
   private Photo photo;
}

After
public class Person {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id_pessoa")
   private int idPessoa;

   @Column(name="id_arquivo_foto")
   private Long photoId;

   @Transient
   private Photo photo;
}
```

And call PhotoDao in the PersonDAO.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
Configuration cfg1 = new AnnotationConfiguration();
cfg1.configure("/hibernate-oracle.cfg.xml");
cfg1.addAnnotatedClass(SomeClass.class); // mapped classes
cfg1.addAnnotatedClass(SomeOtherClass.class);
SessionFactory sf1 = cfg1.buildSessionFactory();

Configuration cfg2 = new AnnotationConfiguration();
cfg2.configure("/hibernate-mysql.cfg.xml");
cfg2.addAnnotatedClass(SomeClass.class); // could be the same or different than above
cfg2.addAnnotatedClass(SomeOtherClass.class);
SessionFactory sf2 = cfg2.buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: I created two files with session configuration, I believe that is my mistake.
The mapping is in an xml.
In your case how would I make the return? Since it has two session factory.
       My mode: Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
   configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
   ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
     .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
   SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
   return(sessionFactory);

Comment: No, despite being a student this is an independent project to learn, some people told me to use spring, but because I did not know how to manipulate, I preferred to do it by hand. It's not possible?

Comment: Well with spring it is easier but then you have to learn spring and it's magic. If I were you I would do exactly like you are doing to understand how stuff works. Just expose both sessionfactories, either with two methods or one method returning a map.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got in another way